# Whitespace at the every first character of the string while printing it

Tags: c++, string, removing-whitespace

This program takes a line, separates each word and adds them into a vector. But while printing the strings from vector after the first word all the remaining words contain a whitespace character at the beginning. I want those whitespaces to be removed.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void addmember(string s) {
    vector<string> vlist;
    string buf;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if(s[i] == ' ') {
            buf.push_back('\0');
            vlist.push_back(buf);
            buf.erase();
        }
        buf.push_back(s[i]);
    }
    for(auto it : vlist) {
        cout << it << "\t" << it.size() << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    string s = "A friend is someone who knows all about you";
    addmember(s);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
A
 friend
 is
 someone
 who
 knows
 all
 about
```

Comment: I failed to see the definition of vlist, does this code even compile? No

Comment: There's already standard library facility to do this: `istringstream v(s); while ( v >> buf ) vlist.push_back(buf);`

Answer (score 2):

You push the character onto the `buf` string even if it is a whitespace.

Put `buf.push_back(s[i])` in a `else` branch.

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (s[i] == ' ') {
        vlist.push_back(buf);
        buf.erase();
    }
    else {
        buf.push_back(s[i]);
    }
}
```

**Edit**: As you use `string`s in the vector as well as `cout <<` and not `char*`/`char[]` one can assume you only want C++ style strings.

If so, you should also remove the insertion of `\0` terminators at the end of each substring. C++ `string`s are not zero terminated.

Comment: @M.M without knowing the requirements, you cannot make that statement. Maybe OP needs zero terminated substrings in `vlist`. Sure, you can easily produce them via `c_str` but it's not *incorrect* to do this.

Comment: OP outputs the strings with `cout <<` so we can tell that having `\0` in the string is not intended

Comment: Of course. By intuition, but not by exclusion. I'll remove the terminator.

Answer (score 0):

You `push_back()` every `s[i]`, no matter what it is. You want to do that only if `s[i]` is not a space:

```
for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
    if(s[i] == ' '){
        vlist.push_back(buf);
        buf.erase();
    } else {
        buf.push_back(s[i]);
    }
}
```